# Integrating python in C# using pythonnet

Tags: python, c#, .net, python.net

```
using System;
using Python.Runtime;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        myFunction("pythonscript.py");
    }

    static void myFunction(string scriptName)
    {
        Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Python311\python311.dll";
        PythonEngine.Initialize();
        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            dynamic python_script = Py.Import(scriptName);
            dynamic results = python_script.my_function();
            Console.WriteLine(results);
        }
    }
}
```

Im trying to run a python script in c#.net. However, I receive this error, and I dont think it's because of the python path.

"System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Delegates' threw an exception."

This was an attempt to run pandas in c# if there is a better solution in terms of performance, please recommend. (I'm not experienced in C#).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73798072/issues-using-pythonnet-to-embed-python-script-within-c-sharp) suggest that this may happen if you try to use the 32bit python runtime in a Net app that compiles to 64bit. Try compiling your Net application also to 32 bit.