# python311.dll not load in pythonnet libs in .net core in local iis, but works in iis express in visual sudio 2019

Tags: c#, .net-core, iis, dll, python.net

i used pythonnet_netstandard_py37_win 2.5.2 to run numpy method of optimization in .net core3.1, it works properly when i ran in visual studio 2019 in (iis express, any cpu, debug) but when on publish it on iis (on my machie) it gives me error :

```
 `System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Delegates' threw an exception.

 System.DllNotFoundException: Could not load python311.dll.

 System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (126): The specified module could not be found.
```

also set enviroment in enviroment variable of windows has been done(regarding to works in debug mode),
searching many issues didnt give me good answer, this line is belong to my code:

```
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/python311.dll", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

 Runtime.PythonDLL = "python311.dll";

 PythonEngine.Initialize();

        using (Py.GIL())
        { ....
```

could someone help me???

Comment: Wrong bitness 32 vs. 64 bit? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73798072/issues-using-pythonnet-to-embed-python-script-within-c-sharp

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 IIS uses a different user account to run your code, so no doubt results differ.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```cs
Runtime.PythonDLL = "python311.dll";
```

overwrites effect of this line completely:

```cs
SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/python311.dll", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

So Python.NET knows you want python311.dll, but has no idea where to find it.

Comment: how can i address that? it run in iis express in debug mode of visual studio.  should i remove mentioned line?

Comment: Use only the first one and provide full path.

Comment: gives same error.

Comment: It can not possibly give the same error as it never receives string "python311.dll" in that exact form quoted in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are encountering indicates that there is a problem loading the python311.dll library when your application is published on IIS.

You need to ensure that the user account running the IIS application pool has the necessary permissions to access the Python DLL and its folder.

Also, check that your IIS application pool is using the correct bitness (32-bit or 64-bit). If your Python installation and PythonNet are 64-bit, make sure your IIS application pool is configured for 64-bit execution.

Comment: I make 32bit => true  in advance setting of pool in IIS, but unfortunately its not working yet!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue but in a Windows docker container.
I tried to look for the dependencies which python311.dll requires:
[image]

They should be located at C:\Windows\System32.
I copied all of the available dlls from the list on my dev machine to the folder containing the entry point of my app in the docker container and it helped.

Here is my bat script that might help to identify missing dependencies:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set DLL_LIST=VERSION.dll WS2_32.dll api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll bcrypt.dll ADVAPI32.dll KERNEL32.dll VCRUNTIME140.dll api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll

for %%i in (%DLL_LIST%) do (
    if exist C:\Windows\System32\%%i (
        echo [OK] %%i found.
    ) else (
        echo [MISSING] %%i not found!
    )
)

endlocal
pause
```